# Split one list into many by month - C#, Linq

Tags: c#, linq, list, median

I have the following Linq query:

```
List<MonthlySales> monthlySales = (from sale in Sales
                     group sale by new { sale.DateSold.Month, sale.Product.Shop } into ds
                     select new MonthlyTitleSales
                     {
                         Shop = ds.Select(it => it.Product.Shop).FirstOrDefault(),
                         Month = ds.Select(it => it.DateSold.Month).FirstOrDefault(),
                         Year = ds.Select(it => it.DateSold.Year).FirstOrDefault(),
                         USDNumberItemsSold = ds.Where(it => it.USDCut.HasValue).Where(it => it.USDCut != 0).Count(),
                         GBPNumberItemsSold = ds.Where(it => it.GBPCut.HasValue).Where(it => it.GBPCut != 0).Count(),
                         EURNumberItemsSold = ds.Where(it => it.EURCut.HasValue).Where(it => it.EURCut != 0).Count(),
                         USDRevenueTotal = PerformCurrencyConversion(ds.Sum(it => it.USDCut.HasValue ? it.USDCut.Value : 0), 0M, 0M, Currency, endDate),
                         GBPRevenueTotal = PerformCurrencyConversion(0M, ds.Sum(it => it.GBPCut.HasValue ? it.GBPCut.Value : 0), 0M, Currency, endDate),
                         EURRevenueTotal = PerformCurrencyConversion(0M, 0M, ds.Sum(it => it.EURCut.HasValue ? it.EURCut.Value : 0), Currency, endDate),
                     }).OrderBy(it => it.DateSold.Month).ToList();
```

This query gives me a list with the following elements in each list item:
Shop, Month, Year, Revenue Made

What I ultimately need to do is calculate the median of the revenue for all the shops for each month, so I need to get the data ready in such a way that will allow me to do that.

I thought one way might be to break this list into small lists by month but I have my doubts that this is the most efficient solution.

Has anyone any thoughts on this?

Monthly Sales class for anyone who needs to see:

```
public class MonthlySales
    {
        public int Month { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }

        public Shop Shop { get; set; }

        public int USDNumberItemsSold { get; set; }
        public int GBPNumberItemsSold { get; set; }
        public int EURNumberItemsSold { get; set; }
        public int TotalNumberItemsSold { get { return USDNumberItemsSold + GBPNumberItemsSold + EURNumberItemsSold; } }

        public decimal USDRevenueTotal { get; set; }
        public decimal GBPRevenueTotal { get; set; }
        public decimal EURRevenueTotal { get; set; }
        public decimal OverallEarnings { get { return USDRevenueTotal + GBPRevenueTotal + EURRevenueTotal; } }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` to group the list into groups by month.  For example, the following will group by Month (month+year, actually) and then write out to the console all values per month:

```
var grouped = monthlySales.GroupBy(ms => string.Format("{0}-{1}", ms.Month, ms.Year));

foreach(var group in grouped)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Values in month-year of {0}:", group.Key);
     foreach(var ms in group)
         Console.WriteLine("   {0}", ms.USDRevenueTotal);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

GroupBy is a great fit for this problem.  Also consider ToLookup (you can use the same code just change GroupBy into ToLookup).

Differences:

- GroupBy is lazy.
- ToLookup is eager.

---

- GroupBy, due to its lazy nature, depends on the source hanging around in order to produce result.  If the source changes, the GroupBy result will include the change - it is connected.
- ToLookup, due to its eager nature, doesn't care if the source changes or goes away - it is disconnected.

---

- GroupBy returns an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TValue>>`, which is only suitable for looping through.
- ToLookup returns an `ILookup<TKey, TValue>`, which is similar a `Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>>` in that it supports seeking by key, in addition to also being an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TValue>>`.

---

Also - consider alternatives to strings for keys.  Here's an anonymous class serving as a key:

```
var grouped = monthlySales.GroupBy(ms => new {ms.Month, ms.Year});
```